# Adding class doesn't change style

Tags: jquery, css

I have CSS for a submit button (shortened for ease of reading):

```
input[type="submit"] 
{
background-color:#3bb3e0;
padding:10px;
position:relative;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#fff;
border: solid 1px #186f8f;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

When a user if filling out a form, whilst error checking using ajax I want to disable the submit button and change its color if the user enters something wrong, so I use the following jquery:

```
if(response == 0)
{
$("#button").addClass("buttonDisable");
$('#cross').fadeIn();
$('#button').prop('disabled', true);
}
```

The button disables ok but the CSS has no effect as the inspector shows it added after the initial css therefore it is crossed out:

```
input[type="submit"].buttonDisable { background-color:#ccc; border:1px solid #666; }
```

**QUESTION:** How can I make the class have an effect on the button?

Comment: This would be such a hilarious question title on `fashion.stackexchange.com` if it existed :)

Comment: Seems working to me.. http://jsfiddle.net/23UAs/

Comment: @PalashMondal Definitely not working when used as above, reading the result of an ajax call - The inspector shows the class is added but it doesn't change it's style

Comment: The other way round it would be even funnier: `Changing style doesn't add class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
input[type="submit"][disabled] { background-color:#ccc; border:1px solid #666; }
```